# How to keep track of number of Active users in Graphite

Tags: graphite, statsd

I need to keep track of the number of Active user on my web site at any point of time . For this i am incrementing a key named "users.loggedin" every time a user log-in and decrements it, every time a user signs out.

I am sending my metrics to Graphite via StatD.  But based on what i have read "Increment" gives the changes per time interval thus I could see the changes in the Graphite Dashboard, but it shows zero again after some time.

Comment: Do you mean "integral" (http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.10/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.integral)?  Increment is not a graphite function.

Comment: sorry, i was referring to the "counter" metrics of StatsD. I increment the counter by magnitude of 1 when a new user logs-in and decrements it by the same order if user logs out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Configure Graphite for StatsD**

[Did you configure Graphite for usage with StatsD?](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/docs/graphite.md)  You must specify in Graphite configuration how you expect it to handle the data you are sending from StatsD.  This is important because Graphite could be *averaging* your counts instead of *summing* them.

**If sending sparse or "bursty" data**

Confirm that your xFilesFactor is low enough that aggregation produces non null values even with a high rate of nulls.  For example, 100 requests in the first 10 seconds, and none for the remaining 50 seconds in a minute would cause a storage of `100, null, null, null, null, null` which would be summed up to null when the data ages if the XFilesFactor is higher than 1/6.  *Using the statsd recommended graphite configuration handles this*, but it is good to know about... as this can give the appearance of lost data.

**Saving schema or aggregation changes**

If you changed the graphite schema or aggregation settings after any metrics were stored (in whisper = graphite's storage) you'll need to either delete the .wsp files for the metric (graphite will recreate them) or run `whisper-resize.py`.

**Validating settings**

You can verify the settings against some whisper data by running whisper-info.py on a .wsp file. Find the .wsp file for one of your metrics in /graphite/storage/whisper/
Run: `whisper-info.py my_metric_data.wsp`. whisper-info.py output should tell you more about how the storage settings are working.

---

After you've confirmed that your data is accurate, then I'd move on to creating the graph you want in the **UI**:

You might need to use the [hitcount()](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.10/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.hitcount) function for this.

[This post](http://code.hootsuite.com/accurate-counting-with-graphite-and-statsd/) covers what you are after pretty well  (even if you aren't using StatsD).